# Where can I find the columns of each forum-related table in the Moodle database?

Tags: moodle

I have seen all the 9 tables related to a forum [in this diagram](http://www.examulator.com/er/). A screenshot of the relevant part of the diagram is as follows.

**The question is that how can I find out what columns are there in each of these tables?** I tried to google it, but could not find a list of columns in the tables.

[image]

Comment: I had a close vote, so I reworded my question, and now I think it can not get any clearer, but I still got another close vote. :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install MySql Workbench

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Then download the latest database schema from here

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Database_Schema

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Here it is: http://www.examulator.com/er/components/forum.png

[image]

[Reference](http://www.examulator.com/er/)